# pyspark extra column where dates are trasformed to 1, 2 , 3

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe with dates in the format YYYYMM.
These start from 201801.
I now want to add a column where 201801 = 1, 201802 = 2 and so on up until the most recent month which is updated every month.

Kind regards,

wokter

Comment: Please Provide input and ouput and code tried so far. ifu want only the month part to the data.. just extract month from the other column. Pleasent of examples out there to extract month from date fromats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[months_between](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.months_between.html) can be used:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

#some testdata
data = [
[201801],
[201802],
[201804],
[201812],
[202001],
[202010]
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["yyyymm"])

df.withColumn("months", F.months_between(
    F.to_date(F.col("yyyymm").cast(T.StringType()), "yyyyMM"), F.lit("2017-12-01")
    ).cast(T.IntegerType())).show()
```

Output:

```
+------+------+
|yyyymm|months|
+------+------+
|201801|     1|
|201802|     2|
|201804|     4|
|201812|    12|
|202001|    25|
|202010|    34|
+------+------+
```